# use sql to print parent_id and sub id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Lets say I have a table `names` like this

```
|   id  |   parent_id   |   title          |
|    1  |        0      |   Boys           |
|    2  |        0      |   Girls          |
|    3  |        1      |   John           |
|    4  |        2      |   Mary           |
|    5  |        1      |   Felix          |
|    6  |        5      |   Felix-Malcom   |
|    7  |        4      |   Mary-Mali      |
|    8  |        5      |   Felix-Edgar    |
|    9  |        4      |   Mary-Ally      |
|   10  |        3      |   John-Mack      |
```

What is the best method of printing all this data to look like this:

> **Boys**
>
> *John*
>
> John-Mack
>
> *Felix*
>
> Felix-Malcom
>
> Felix-Adgar
>
> **Girls**
>
> *Mary*
>
> Mary-Mali
>
> Mary-Ally

How can I print the data like this? Should I use a inner join or do I have to use a loop inside another loop? What can you recommend?

EDIT:
I dont know if this changes anything, but I use mariadb

Comment: How do you know if a person is a boy or a girl?

Comment: @jarlh Parent ID.

Comment: I guess it should be looping, but people hate that technique quoting performance constraints.

Comment: Do you alway have those three levels (boy/girl, name, composite name) or can the levels number be arbitrary?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, very odd data model... Felix-Malcom is a boy since the parent Felix is a boy?

Comment: It could have been an interesting discussion around names, but the problem are not the names, but how I cant print a series of data when I know the start (parent_id=0)

Comment: You probably want some sort of recursive query, which mysql doesn't natively support.  Search this site for "mysql recursive query" and you'll get some ideas.